# Trying to add styles/change fonts in a random text and image script

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a webpage to open up a random image and text to go along with it. I will be using this to have different events posted on our library's front page. Pulling from different examples on the web I've gotten the basics to work fine with this.

```
   var total_images = 2;
   var random_number = Math.floor((Math.random()*total_images));
   var random_img = new Array();
   var random_text = [];

   random_img[0] = "<a href = 'www.webpage.com'><img src='image_1.jpg' alt='Image'></a>";
   random_text[0] = "<p>Here is some text</p>";    

   random_img[1] = "<a href = 'www.webpage2.com'><img src='image_2.jpg' alt='Image2'></a>";
   random_text[1] = "<p>Here is some text2</p>";

   document.write(random_img[random_number] + ' <br/><p id="myP">' + random_text[random_number] + 'dfsadf</p>');

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myP").style.font = "italic bold 20px arial,serif";
}
```

It works as hoped and on a refresh will display a new event picture and text. What I am having trouble with is I cannot get it to match the styles from the rest of our webpage. I've tried using functions to create a new id, regular html tags and just about anything I can pull from the web. Any time I add anything more to the `random_text[] = "<p>codehere</p>";` than the usual <b> or <i> it breaks the page.

If I can change the fonts to match it would be perfect.

Comment: Please define “it breaks the page”.

Comment: The page loads blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will probably break the page because a `<p>` tag should not be put inside of another `<p>` tag. Try this for the document write:

```
document.write('<div id="myP">' + random_img[random_number] + ' <br/>' + random_text[random_number] + 'dfsadf</div>');
```

And the fonts could be modified using CSS in your HTML page:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #myP p { font:20px arial,sans-serif; }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding in css while using p, h1 and h2 let me change the fonts around.

Comment: Nice, maybe you can accept my answer if it solved all problems :)